# Recorrer tabla genotype en Rstudio

Tags: r, bucle-for, rstudio

resulta que quiero sacar un promedio de todos las A con los A, los A con los B y aspi sucesivamente, como puedo implementar un for para hacer el recorrido de esta y que me devuelva el promedio

```
> library(MASS)
> head(genotype, 25)

   Litter Mother   Wt
1       A      A 61.5
2       A      A 68.2
3       A      A 64.0
4       A      A 65.0
5       A      A 59.7
6       A      B 55.0
7       A      B 42.0
8       A      B 60.2
9       A      I 52.5
10      A      I 61.8
11      A      I 49.5
12      A      I 52.7
13      A      J 42.0
14      A      J 54.0
15      A      J 61.0
16      A      J 48.2
17      A      J 39.6
18      B      A 60.3
19      B      A 51.7
20      B      A 49.3
21      B      A 48.0
22      B      B 50.8
23      B      B 64.7
24      B      B 61.7
25      B      B 64.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

¡Hola!

La pregunta que planteas puede ser resuelta de la siguiente manera:

```
# Cargar librería
  library(MASS)
  library(dplyr)
# Cargar datos
  genotype

# Utilizando "genotipe" que te agrupe los individuos por las variables "Litter"
# y "Mother" y que te calcule la "mean" (media) de los valores de la variable "WtW
  genotype %>% 
           group_by(Litter,Mother) %>%
           summarise_at(vars(Wt), list(name=mean))
```

Obteniendo de esta forma como resultado

```
   Litter Mother  name
      <fct>  <fct>  <dbl>
    1 A      A       63.7
    2 A      B       52.4
    3 A      I       54.1
    4 A      J       49.0
    5 B      A       52.3
    6 B      B       60.6
    7 B      I       53.9
    8 B      J       45.9
    9 I      A       47.1
   10 I      B       64.4
   11 I      I       51.6
   12 I      J       49.4
   13 J      A       54.4
   14 J      B       56.1
   15 J      I       54.5
   16 J      J       49.1
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, si me funcionó

Answer (score 1):

Lo que estás buscando, es armar grupos por `Litter` y `Mother` y en cada uno calcular el promedio. Con R base, puedes hacer:

```
aggregate(Wt ~  Litter + Mother, genotype, mean)
```

La formula indica, la variable a sumarizar (`Wt`) y las variables de agrupación, indicando finalmente la función de agregación, en este caso `mean()`